# Give an explicit atlas for the manifold $\mathbb{R}P^3$ which is defined as the quotient of the three-sphere by the antipodal mapping.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I'd like to know if there is an explicit atlas for the manifold $\mathbb{R}P^3$ which is defined as the quotient of the three-sphere by the antipodal mapping.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take first an explicit atlas for $\mathbb{S}^3 $
$\phi_{i, \pm}\colon U_{i, \pm} \to D_3$ where $U_{i, \pm} = \{ x \in \mathbb{S}^3 \ | \ \pm x_i >0\}$, with $\phi_{i,\pm}$ the projection onto the components with index not $i$. This is an atlas for $\mathbb{S}^3 $. It's strongly recommended to check for oneself.

Note now that the restriction of the canonical projection $\mathbb{S}^3\to \mathbb{R}P^3$ is injective. Take $\bar U_{i,\pm}$ the image of this set. It will be an open subset in  $\mathbb{R}P^3$. Consider the map 
$\bar \phi_{i,\pm} \to D_3$ to be the composition of the $\phi_{i, \pm}$ with the inverse of the restriction of the projection $\mathbb{S}^3\to \mathbb{R}P^3$.

One checks that we get again an atlas. The only thing that we are using is that the restriction $\mathbb{S}^3\to \mathbb{R}P^3$ is injective. (the identifying is done in a structured way). The coordinate changes are OK since they are also coordinate changes for the atlas of $\mathbb{S}^3$.

The same argument works for any $\mathbb{S}^n$. It is useful to look at the picture for the cases of $\mathbb{S}^1$ and $\mathbb{S}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

For any $n$, real projective $n$-space $\Bbb P^n(\Bbb R)$ is actually isomorphic to the quotient
$$
\frac{\Bbb R^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}}\sim\qquad 
\text{where $u\sim v$ iff $u=\lambda v$ for some $\lambda\in\Bbb R^\times$.}
$$
Then to every point $P\in\Bbb P^n(\Bbb R)$ one can associate its homogeneus coordinates $P=[u_0,u_1,...,u_n]$ which are defined up to a scalar (they are the coordinates of any $\tilde P\in\Bbb R^{n+1}$ representing $P$).

Then the standard atlas is made up by the $n+1$ charts
$$
U_i=\{u_i\neq 0\}.
$$
One sees that $U_i\simeq\Bbb R^n$ simply normalizing $u_i=1$ in the homogeneous coordinates of its points.

At this point, it is a straightforward exercise to write the transition functions.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, actually I know about this construction. My problem is constructing an atlas for the projective space as defined in the statement of my problem.

Comment: Well, since the inclusion $S^3\subset\Bbb R^4$ is compatible with the equivalences, shouldn't be too hard to use the standard atlas I described to give one in terms of $S^3$, if you wish.

Comment: I'll work on this. Thanks.